# How to efficiently operate on two joined tables in Ruby On Rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have two tables: Transfers and Releases. I need to join them in one ordered array

```
@transfers = Transfer.includes(:shipment,batch: %i[products material], sender: :profile).where(receiver: @dispensary, material: { id: material.id }, batch: { capacity: capacity }).where.not(shipment: { delivery_date: nil })

@outgoing_transfers = Transfer.includes(:shipment, batch: %i[products material]).where(sender: @dispensary, material: { id: material.id }, batch: { capacity: capacity }).where.not(shipment: { delivery_date: nil })
    
return if @releases.empty? && @transfers.empty? && @outgoing_transfers.empty?

@operations = (@releases + @transfers + @outgoing_transfers).sort_by(&:updated_at).paginate(page: params[:page],per_page: 27)
```

As you can see there is a problem. Each time I want to see another 27 records (I'm using 'will-paginate' gem) it's fire this queries again. Is there a way to do this only once and then operate on this array?

Ps. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

"Operating on array" means loading everything in memory - this is a dangerous strategy that could literally kill your app with the dataset large enough.

You could try building a view for smth like `select ... from transfers union select .. from releases` and working with it (should be easily doable with ActiveRecord too, if necessary - by setting the proper table name and making a model read-only).

Or even question your data design - if transfers and releases are isomorphic to some extent and can be used in the same context, maybe they could be modeled using single table inheritance (or even the same entity with some `kind`-like property if the difference is really minor?)